# Sharepoint Add-ins vs Sharepoint Web-parts

Tags: web-part

Can someone explain to me the difference between the two and why I'd use one over the other?  I'm very new to Sharepoint am needing all the help I can get.

Comment: Hi @WaqasSarwarMCSE ,I agree with you,  it's duplicated but the answer in the main post is not up to date where auto-hosted has been deprecated and the app name become add-in , I know you know that but the answer in the main post doesn't mention that ,

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint Web Part**

- Web Part is a reusable component or a server side control that can be added inside a SharePoint page.
- Web Part code runs directly on the SharePoint server.
- There are several out-of-box Web Parts available in SharePoint and one can also build their own custom Web Parts.
- You can use Server Side Object Model / CSOM via C# .

For  more details check [Creating Web Parts for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231579.aspx)

**SharePoint Add-In**

- Add-ins can be developed on both SharePoint Online and in On-Premise offerings.
- Add-ins don't have custom code that runs on the SharePoint servers.
- Almost all major types of SharePoint components can be part of a SharePoint Add-in, including pages, lists, workflows, custom content types, list templates, Web Parts, and more.
- There are two basic kinds of SharePoint Add-ins —

  - SharePoint-hosted and
  - provider-hosted.
- Add-in can be published to Microsoft’s public SharePoint store or hosted in a private store.
- Provide you with the simplest marketing and sales system based on a Microsoft online add-in store.
- Maximize your flexibility in developing future upgrades.
- Maximize your ability to take advantage of your existing non-SharePoint programming skills.

For more details check [SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930.aspx)